# parse error on input `=' in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parse-error

I wrote the following function in Haskell

```
coordenadas :: (Floating a) => String -> (a, a, a)
coordenadas linea = (x, y, z)
    where  (_ : xStr : yStr : zStr : _) = words linea
           x = read $ tail xStr :: Float
           y = read $ tail yStr :: Float
           z = read $ tail zStr :: Float
```

This function is meant to receive a string like `"N1 X2 Y1 Z10"` and produce a tuple like `(2, 1, 10)`, but when I try to compile it, the compiler says that there's a `parse error on input '='` in the line `x = read $ tail xStr :: Float`.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: The code compiles fine (well, not really, since `x` has type `Float` and your type signature indicates it should have type `Floating a => a`) but there is no parse error, on that line or any other.

Comment: I'm betting it's an indentation problem, but can you give an example of a valid value of `linea`?

Comment: Thanks, it was, in fact, an indentation problem. I'm beginner in Haskell.

Comment: Indentation problem is very popular. If you want to forget about it, I advice you to use [emacs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Emacs) + [haskell-mode](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode) if you like emacs. If you don't, this is a good point to start, because emacs is pretty awesome. Anyway, there are even few options for [vim](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Vim). If you don't like them both, there is a plugin for [sublime text](https://github.com/SublimeHaskell/SublimeHaskell). But there is one more choice: [haskell web ide](https://www.fpcomplete.com). It's really great :)

Answer (score 5):

I got it working:

```
coordinates :: String -> (Float, Float, Float)
coordinates line = (x,y,z)
    where   (_ : xStr : yStr : zStr : _) = words line
            x = read $ tail xStr :: Float
            y = read $ tail yStr :: Float
            z = read $ tail zStr :: Float

main = do
    let line = "test x1.0 y1.0 z1.0 test"
    print $ coordinates line
```

This outputs `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` as expected.

I'm kind of new to Haskell myself, so I have no idea why it's *this* picky about indentation (and would appreciate pointers from people who know more than I do!), but apparently the correct way is:

- *tab*, `where`, *tab again*, then type the first line
- *tab 3 times*, then line up future lines with that one

(NOTE: In my editor "tab" is "4 spaces", not a tab character)

EDIT: I think I just figured out why it was hard to line up on my end: syntax highlighting! My editor bolded "where", which made it wider, which made the correct indentation look incorrect. I actually confirmed this by turning off highlighting and it appears to work as long as the lines are aligned with each other.

This also means that this way probably avoids similar problems:

```
coordinates :: String -> (Float, Float, Float)
coordinates line = (x,y,z)
    where 
        (_ : xStr : yStr : zStr : _) = words line
        x = read $ tail xStr :: Float
        y = read $ tail yStr :: Float
        z = read $ tail zStr :: Float
```

Comment: Nearly everyone considers the proper approach to be not using tabs.

Comment: @Carl, Sorry, I should have made it clearer that my editor converts tabs to 4 spaces. Python is my primary language so that's pretty much beaten into me already. :)

Comment: In that case, the rule is simple: every declaration within a where block needs to start in the same column. Whatever column the first declaration starts in, the remaining declarations need to align to it.

Comment: That's the same rule for everything else that uses layout, by the way - multiple declarations in a let, multiple statements in a do, etc. Just align them to all match the first one, wherever you put the first one.

Comment: @Carl: Good to know, thanks. I think I shouldn't have any more problems now that I found out about the syntax highlighting issue I edited into my answer (I never noticed before because Python only ever aligns for the beginning of a line, where variable character widths never affect anything)

Comment: @jozefg Notepad++. It looks like this was the fault of the specific theme I was using, so I've already fixed it. (learning vim is one of those things I keep procrastinating)

Comment: Presumably Notepad++ can use a fixed-width font, too.

Comment: Damn Notepad++. Going into a new line for the first where statement when using at least two of them finally worked.

Comment: @user3764804 yeah, if you're getting into Haskell I would triple-check that whatever syntax highlighting you're using never increases the font width. Otherwise you always risk these kinds of spooky errors where things look lined up and they're not.